# D3.JS add zoom and listitems to rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to achieve followings,

1 - Create a given column matrix with rectangles with provided colours
 **Done**

2 - Make this matrix zoom able

3 - Add list items to each rectangle which will only show numbers of list items in it if completely zoomed out and on zoom in, it will show the list items e.g. there Titles.

Now I want to achieve Number 2 here, this is what I am trying,

http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/25/

When I add code for zooming it fails,

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 300)
                                    .attr("height", 300)
                                    .style("background-color", "black");

var zoomed = function () {
    svgContainer.attr("transform", "translate("+ d3.event.translate + ")
    scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 8])
.on("zoom", zoomed);
.size([width, height]);



var rectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red")
                            .call(zoom);;


var rectangle2 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");

var rectangle3 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 0)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");

var rectangle4 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");


var rectangle5 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");

var rectangle6 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 100)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");


var rectangle7 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 0)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");


var rectangle8 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 100)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "yellow");

var rectangle9 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 200)
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("width", 100)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("fill", "red");
```

My desired result will be this,

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided has several problems:
1. There is a syntax error in definition of zoom (.on("zoom", zoomed);)
2. You haven't defined width and height.
3. zoomed function possibly couldn't be parsed because of wrong line breaks (notice point where you define scale of transformation).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lggfn9pu/) is JSFiddle, where zoom works correctly for first element of matrix. Main points is:

```
// don't forget about width and height
var width = 960,
height = 500;

// make sure that string defining transform attribute is correct. scale isn't a method, but part of string
var zoomed = function () {
    svgContainer.attr("transform", "translate("+ d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

// don't place semicolon after on("zoom", zoomed)
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 8])
.on("zoom", zoomed)
.size([width, height]);

// add zoom behaviour to desired rectangle
var rectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", 0)
                        .attr("y", 0)
                        .attr("width", 100)
                        .attr("height", 100)
                        .attr("fill", "red")
                        .call(zoom);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mrkrakhin, I added your suggestions here - http://jsfiddle.net/nhe613kt/36/, but I can't see my matrix zooming in or out at all..., please accept my +1

Comment: @yaron it's because I added zoom handler only to upper left rectangle (you could try zooming on it, it works). I think you could create svg group inside matrix and place your rectangles there and then call zoom on group. I'm not near computer now, so cannot test.

Comment: @yaron btw, I tested your jsfiddle and it works (win, firefox 37.0.1).